# android studio Device [emulator-5554] is online, waiting for processes to start up

Tags: android-studio

I have installed Android studio, and i am trying to run a very simple program but my emulator device display android on the splash screen. I waited 10 mins but no change, read some forum i tried enabling "Use host GPU" but nothing has changed

Comment: Have you tried different AVDs with different API levels? I'm now using Android Studio 1.4. When I select an AVD with API 21, I get the same issue as yours. Then I select another AVD with API 19, and it works. Then I select a 3rd AVD with API 17, and it works also. I suspect that a specific Android Studio version works only with AVDs of some specific API levels. Usually it is safer to select an AVD of low API level.